# How to delete temp folders created for live booting?

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, opensuse, live-usb

I have followed this document for live USB creations for opensuse13.2, https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media. Accidentally, i have used sd instead of sdx, hence it created some/tmp files in my HDD which is cannot be deleted. When i try to delete it throws some exception as those partitions are not mountable. Any idea?

This is completely eaten my booting options, There is a GRUB installed and but not getting detected, only my my previously installed opensuse is booting by default.

**Edit**
When i try loading a live boot DVD the system gone abandon with a blank screen.Sounds like the HDD installed partitions are really bothering.

Comment: Did you use `dd`, or another program? I don't even have a `/dev/sd` on Mint (debian based) so trying to use it *should* fail. And it's lit literally "sdx"

Comment: @Xen2050, Yes, i just used dd command. /dev/sd didn't throw me any error and did what it suppose to, but with my HDD. I have tried with my opensuse machine.

Answer (score 1):

So you probably overwrote the beginning of your hard drive, I guess you're lucky anything it booting from it. I'd expect it's written it's own partition & maybe even MBR/GPT.

Using a good live cd/dvd/usb should let you delete the new unwanted partition(s) and attempt to fix things, but restoring the overwritten data from a backup may be required.

When running "live" you don't have to be able to mount a partition to delete it (can use a program like `gparted`), in fact it may have to be ***un***-mounted first.

A live cd/dvd/usb shouldn't touch the hard drive when booting, at least every linux I've seen doesn't (tested Debian & Red Hat based, others shouldn't either). Maybe you've got BIOS setup / boot problems, and it's not actually trying to boot from USB or even DVD. For testing you could try unplugging the power from your HD and then see if you can boot from a known good live DVD?

Comment: ,Thanks.As my edit says in the question. I am unable to perform a live boot as well, as the tmps are mounted to the System see here for more details. http://paste.opensuse.org/889856

Comment: A live cd/dvd/usb shouldn't touch the hard drive when booting, at least every linux I've seen doesn't (tested Debian & Red Hat based, others shouldn't either). Maybe you've got BIOS setup / boot problems, and it's not actually trying to boot from USB or even DVD. For testing you could try unplugging the power from your HD and then see if you can boot from a known good live DVD?

Comment: I am unlucky to try these in my office laptop :P